# How do I place an image over a video header

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my image header right now. I want to keep the video, but add some text on top (a logo) Like these: https://www.pexels.com/blog/video-header-inspiration/

```
<div class="video-container">
   <video autoplay loop muted>
         <source src="http://www.icutpeople.com/wp-content/themes/icutpeople/assets/video/waynesworld.mp4" type="video/mp4">

   </video>
 <div class="overlay-desc">
    <h1>Wayne's World</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

     body {
    background: #333;
    }
     .video-container {
     position: relative;
     }
     video {
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
   width: 100%;
    }
   .overlay-desc {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
   display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would insert your text into the `<h1>` tag. The codepen that this is sampled from, the creator added text over the video by putting text in the div "overlay-desc".

So if you change the text there, and change the video source to the video link you have, you'll be good.

Here's without their content:

```
<div class="video-container">

   <video autoplay loop muted>
      <source src="YOUR LINK HERE" type="video/mp4">
   </video>

   <div class="overlay-desc">
      <h1>YOUR TEXT HERE</h1>
   </div>

</div>
```

But keep all of the CSS.

**EDIT**

To put an image (such as a logo) over the video, you would switch the divs to look like this:

```
    <div class="full-containter">
      <div class="img-container"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/31/20/20/bowler-1295700_1280.png"/></div>
      <video autoplay muted loop>
         <source src="http://www.icutpeople.com/wp-content/themes/icutpeople/assets/video/waynesworld.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
```

The CSS you can play with a bit, there are a couple of different ways to achieve it. Some use float, some use z-index. I'm able to achieve the result by doing:

```
.full-container {
  height: 100vh;
}

video {
  position: relative;
}

.img-container {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Hope this helps a little more!

Comment: I just realized I said text *face-palm* how would I go about putting an image instead?

Comment: Ah! My apologies! I also see that you indeed correctly worded the title, stating and image over a video. I'll edit to make it more relevant.